# Photos app not importing all files

Tags: photos, photos.app, import

I have over 58,000 photos stored on a HD from the past 15 or so years. I now have a brand new Macbook pro and I have been trying to import all these photos into the Photos app. I have been importing them in batches however, not all of the photos in each batch are uploaded. In the Review for Import window it lists the correct count, but then after uploading the total amount is less (usually around 500-600). I do not get any errors after this.

And then when I try to import the same batch again to see if it picks up on the missing photos, it sees that a really small amount (like 40) haven't been imported and will let me click on import but that doesn't actually do anything and no extra photos have been imported. I have checked these photos specifically, and they have not previously been imported into the Photos app.

I have tried restarting my machine, ejecting the HD and reconnecting it, restoring the library, deleting the library and starting again and renaming all my photos to ensure there are no duplicate file names. I have counted all the .AAE and edited file types (IMG_Exxx) but the numbers don't add up. All apps and my machine are up to date.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe some of the files are corrupt but that seems unlikely as I can view them all in Finder. The photos I am having trouble with are actually the newer ones (from 2016 to this year). Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: If you start with an empty library and then just import one of the photos which failed before, does it get imported?

Comment: @nohillside Yeah it imported, weirdly. Took me ages to find just one photo that wasnt imported though!